# Target elements in Dom matching with Classes present in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a Array of classes, its a dynamic Array which can have n number of class names like this.

```
let arr = ['Product', 'year', 'role'];
```

and then I have lots of elements with these classes inside a parent div like this.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="year"></div>
    <div class="abc"></div>
    <div class="Product"></div>
    <div class="diffClass"></div>
    <div class="role"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Now in this structure I need to add class active on page load only on the div's which's class present in the Array.
I tried to map the array but no table to get the divs with matching with Arrays class
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can select "or" classes using `,`, eg

```
$(".product,.year,.role")
```

will select if any of them match
(conversely, to make them all match, use `.product.year.role` - that's not the requirement here)

To convert your array to a string, use `arr.join`, giving:

```js
let arr = ['Product', 'year', 'role'];

$("." + arr.join(",.")).addClass("active");
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="year">year</div>
    <div class="abc">abc</div>
    <div class="Product">Product</div>
    <div class="diffClass">diffClass</div>
    <div class="role">role</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working for the classes , thanks for the same, but what if I need to do the same and not for classes but for attributes, lets say there is an attribute name relation="Product" or anything else from the Array, how to target this?

Comment: $("[realated='product']","[realated='year']","[realated='role']")
this is what I need now, sorry for the requirement change

Comment: Make sure the selector is a single string, but otherwise, yes:  `$("[related='product'][related='year'],[related='role']")`